# Separate Windows 10 User Separate Wifi settings

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to have 2 users in Windows. I don't want the saved password of User A to work on User B,

Like I have Wifi A saved on User A. Now what happens is that if I create new Windows user, it automatically have that Wifi connected by default. I don't want that. It shouldn't connect to it until I put the password in it.

Hope anyone can help me

Comment: You can't - all connections are available to all users. The only way you can make it work is for logout to delete all saved credentials, forcing everyone to re-enter their passwords every time. But this is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Harry. That sucks though :/